# What is the meaning of "override types" in this JSON code in this spreadsheet for creating a custom PvZ2 level?

Tags: json, variables

So I was using [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-98cfNHgsZG7PlzVJmq5vGBIylQQz2dbC6GcxTYtj_Y/copy) spreadsheet to create a custom PvZ2 level. Even though I might never export *any* custom level that I make, I usually enjoy looking at the full level code to look at the code for fun. (Under the sheet "Level Code" for anyone who doesn't know.) Now, I was looking at the code when I came upon this:

```
{"aliases": ["WaveManager"],
"objclass": "WaveManagerProperties",
    "FlagWaveInterval": 5,
    "FlagWaveVeteranOverrideTypes": [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
    "WaveCount": 40,
    "SuppressFlagZombie": false,
    "MinNextWaveHealthPercentage": 1,
    "MaxNextWaveHealthPercentage": 1,
    "ZombieCountdownFirstWaveSecs": 5,
    "ZombieCountdownFirstwaveConveyorSecs": 5,
    "ZombieCountdownHugeWaveDelay": 10,
    "Waves": [
        ["RTID(Wave1@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm1_C3@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm1_C4@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm1_2_C3@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm1_2_C4@.)"],
        ["RTID(Wave2@.)", "RTID(GroundSpawn2_C9@.)", "RTID(GroundSpawn2_C10@.)", "RTID(GroundSpawn2_C11@.)", "RTID(GroundSpawn2_C12@.)", "RTID(GroundSpawn2_C13@.)"],
        ["RTID(Wave3@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm3_C5@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm3_C6@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm3_C7@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm3_C8@.)"],
        ["RTID(Wave4@.)", "RTID(GroundSpawn4_C10@.)", "RTID(GroundSpawn4_C11@.)"],
        ["RTID(Wave5@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm5_C4@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm5_C5@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm5_C6@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm5_C7@.)"],
        ["RTID(Wave6@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm6_C4@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm6_C5@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm6_C6@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm6_C7@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm6_C8@.)"],
        ["RTID(Wave7@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm7_C3@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm7_C4@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm7_C6@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm7_C7@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm7_C8@.)"],
        ["RTID(Wave8@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm8_C4@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm8_C5@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm8_C6@.)"],
        ["RTID(Wave9@.)"],
        ["RTID(Wave10@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm10_C4@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm10_C5@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm10_C6@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm10_C7@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm10_C8@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm10_2_C3@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm10_2_C4@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm10_2_C5@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm10_2_C6@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm10_2_C7@.)", "RTID(Sandstorm10_2_C8@.)", "RTID(GroundSpawn10_C9@.)", "RTID(GroundSpawn10_C10@.)", "RTID(GroundSpawn10_C11@.)", "RTID(GroundSpawn10_C12@.)", "RTID(GroundSpawn10_C13@.)"]
    ]
}},
```

### Note:

> 1. I most likely probably could have gotten away with not writing the entire code for the waves, however, I just felt like it might have at least some importance to what I'm asking.

> 2. This is not something I forgot to put in, Wave 9 actually *has* no events happening, so that's why there is a `],` right after the `["RTID(Wave9@.)"` instead of a bunch of events that happen.

> 3. Note that this is not a conveyor level, `"ZombieCountdownFirstwaveConveyorSecs:"` I'm pretty sure is coded in there by default.

> 4. The reason that I end the section of code with `}},` instead of `}` is because there is *a lot* of code after it and I don't think that I would need to type that much code to get my point across honestly.

> 5. I put the code for the events in so the question doesn't get flagged/closed/deleted due to missing/broken code.

> 6. The reason the I can tell that this is JSON code is because of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wma1qgqL1yI) video because it mentions a JSON code editor and in the description, it says
>
> "JSON Editor: [https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=lo...](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqa3BfNE5Gc2FCMTBoSDV2dUxSakdYMUY0eHFhZ3xBQ3Jtc0tuN2xnV21IWEUtWkxGNTgyNDhoZVBhMmN6eW1UX19RdlVkdXZVaXh1TGMwNFJQRDRfTGNxZXg4NDZENUh5UVdWWlhLUjFKSEdXcFhMZ2trZGFleUtvMnlQN0xodTdLMVF2aE4ySm83dTk0cEpLQVVWRQ&q=https%3A%2F%2Fjsoneditoronline.org%2F%23left%3Dlocal.zodica&v=Wma1qgqL1yI)"

Sorry I had to put it in 6 different spoilers, it's either that or I have to make it flow clearly with 1 full note, which I don't think that I might be able to do honestly. :\

---

---

## My question

---

What does "`OverrideTypes`" in "`FlagWaveVeteranOverrideTypes`" mean in this case? I'm not exactly that familiar with JSON code, so any explanation would be appreciated.